# Should sidebars be inside <main>?

Tags: html

I'm unsure about the `<main>` element's relation to a site's sidebar, and would appreciate some guidance, or at least communal majority consensus. ;) Given the following page elements:

```
<body>
    <header>Logo and stuff</header>
    <nav>Main Nav</nav>
    ...
    <footer>Copyright blah</footer>
</body>
```

How should the `<main>` element and a sidebar element be arranged, if replacing the `...`?

Option 1:

```
<main>
    <article>...</article>
    <div class='sidebar'>Sidebar</div>
</main>
```

Option 2:

```
<main>
    <article>...</article>
</main>
<div class='sidebar'>Sidebar</div>
```

Option 3:

```
  #####
 #     #
       #
    ###
    #

    #
```

Comment: I'd run with option 3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main): (emphasis mine)

> The content of a `<main>` element should be unique to the document or
>   section the element contains. **Content** that is repeated across a set of
>   documents or document sections **such as sidebars**, navigation links,
>   copyright information, site logos, and search forms **should not be
>   included** unless the search form is the main function of the page.

So Option 2 would seem to be the idiomatic choice.

Comment: Please add backticks around the `<main>` bit in your quote. I tried to add them as suggested edits, but "edits have to be at least 6 characters different".